# PayPal: IPN/REST/Webhooks integration with Java Program

Tags: java, post, paypal, paypal-ipn, webhooks

I have been doing research for a couple of hours and haven't found any viable examples or information on how I could receive PayPal notifications for payments and process them within a Java Application.

What I want to do is:

- Person makes payment.
- PayPal sends a notification to the java program, indicating that they had made a payment, with email, usernames, amount, package name/ID, etc.
- Java program processes the payment.

Perhaps I am looking at it the wrong way. So far I have found out that I need a webhook listener or some kind of IPN serverlet program that can read the POST messages PayPal sends and redirect them? Can't this be done directly within my java program?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, you really need to use Webhook (which is newer in PayPal) or IPN. This technologies let you to configure PayPal to send (as POST requests) certain events on a certain URLs. All you need to do in your program is to handle this events (requests) in Serlvet, RestHandler or whatever else.